# Why is appended script running twice in IE8 and IE9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm doing the client-side work for an ASP.NET app, and the function below works across browsers:

```
$('#identifier').click(function () {
    $('#script-placeholder').append('<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="SERVICEURL?callback=test"></script>');
});
```

When I click on the element with an ID of 'identifier', the service sends back a response wrapped in a JS function call (i.e.

```
test('response');
```

However, in IE8 and IE9, if I execute the script once, navigate to a different page, then back and click 'identifier' again, the callback function is getting called twice. Anyone have any ideas why or know of a workaround? Any help would be greatly appreciated! (Note that I'm encountering this problem on on localhost)...

Comment: May be you can try to clear the content of #script-placeholder before append?

Comment: Thanks, Zeal. I did try that approach, but IE still seemed to be caching the script tag for some reason... Getscript ended up working for me. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches i know

approach 1:-
Add some additional parameter in the URL before call.

```
$('#identifier').click(function () {
     $('#script-placeholder').append('<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="SERVICEURL?callback=test&t="+Math.random()></script>');
});
```

above is just an example. you will have to check in your situation.

another is

set no cache in your service page as follows if you are using `generic handler`

```
    context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Comment: Thanks, krshekhar! The first suggestion you gave is exactly what jQuery's $.getScript function does for me. The second option would work, too. I didn't think about it (especially since I'm not very well-versed on the server side of the code). Thanks, again!

Comment: So, does this mean that I can never cache scripts in IE?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for your answers! I was reading around after I posted the question and saw that there's another way to make the call instead of adding the script tag: jQuery's getScript... That ended up working for me. Here's how I used it:

```
    $('#identifier').click(function () {
        var url = 'SERVICEURL?callback=test'
        $.getScript(url);
    });
```

Hopefully, this helps someone in the future! FYI: after doing more reading on Jquery's site, I found this (which is how they get get around the caching problem): Be default, $.getScript() sets the cache setting to false. This appends a timestamped query parameter to the request URL to ensure that the browser downloads the script each time it is requested.